# how to get default /usr/share/vim folder back on ubuntu

Tags: vim

I was messing with by profile and ended up deleting /usr/share/vim folder and everything in it.  How can I get this folder back?

```
sudo aptitude reinstall vim
```

did not help

Answer (score 1):

```
% sudo apt-get remove vim
% sudo apt-get install vim
```